# How to use and store multiple tokens based on domain subfolder?

Tags: git, gitlab

My company has segregated access to repos by project ID.  So, the repos are stored in the following manner:

- https://gitlab.company.com/project1/*  (contains repos and subdirectories of repos)
- https://gitlab.company.com/project2/*  (contains repos and subdirectories of repos)
- ...

Each project has its own Deployment or Group token.  We have a common build server that needs access to multiple project directories and use the project Deployment or Group Access token.  I would like to configure the build machine to store the token credentials for the projects.

- First, the company mandates using HTTPS instead of SSH to retrieve repos.
- I upgraded GIT to make use of wildcards.  Wildcards don't seem to work in my attempts.
- "git config --global credential.helper store" will store passwords but "git config --global credential.https://gitlab.company.com/project1/*.helper store" does not store passwords.
- I set "git config --global credential.https://gitlab.company.com.useHttpPath true".  This seems to ask for credentials for all repos in the domain rather than relying on one credential per project directory.

Here is my gitconfig file:

```
[credential "https://gitlab.company.com/project1/*"]
        helper = store
        username = project1-Deploy-Token
[credential "https://gitlab.company.com"]
        useHttpPath = true
        helper = store
```

I upgraded GIT on RH7.9 to GIT 2.41.0.

How do I create a global config file to use particular tokens based on a project name/folder on the same gitlab server domain?

Comment: Is this meant to use the same username for each project, just with different tokens? Or is this a different username+token combo for each?

Comment: different username +token combo.